# Call server-signing service with Base64 encoded certificate in DSS

Tags: rest, digital-signature, electronic-signature, p12

I need to execute `tok:sign` request of [DSS](https://github.com/esig/dss) with a given certificate instead of an alias.

```
<alias>certificate</alias>
```

I tried to replace below one with a base64 string, but got following error in log.

> INFO | http-nio-8080-exec-3 |
>   o.a.cxf.services.SoapSignatureTokenConnection.FAULT_OUT | FAULT_OUT

Sample, original SOAP request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tok="http://token.dss.esig.europa.eu/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tok:sign>
         <toBeSigned>
            <bytes>wFNeS+K3n/2TKRMFQ2v4iTFOSj+uwF7P/Lt98xrZ5Ro=</bytes>
         </toBeSigned>
         <digestAlgorithm>SHA256</digestAlgorithm>
         <alias>certificate</alias>
      </tok:sign>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I already added certificate to `cacerts` file, but unable to retrieve with `getKeys` SOAP request. Or on the other way, how could I add a new p12 to server-side to make it available by an alias?

Comment: How are you launching the SOAP server? I assume you are instantiating `SoapSignatureTokenConnectionImpl` in some way. It can be provided with `setToken(RemoteSignatureTokenConnection token)`. So you will need to initialize a `RemoteSignatureTokenConnection` with your .p12.  See this [test](https://github.com/esig/dss/blob/fb023db0d981595c4d808c9cee8484954076cc32/dss-server-signing-common/src/test/java/eu/europa/esig/dss/token/RemoteSignatureTokenConnectionImplTest.java) You can create a `Pkcs12SignatureToken` with p12 and password

Comment: @pedrofb : I got some help about p12, it is defined here: https://github.com/esig/dss-demonstrations/blob/master/dss-demo-webapp/src/main/resources/dss.properties#L14 So to change it project rebuild is needed. I downloaded whole project, but got error messages like this during build: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [eu.europa.esig.dss.x509.tsp.MockTSPSource] for bean with name 'tspSource' defined in class path resource [config/tsp-config.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eu.europa.esig.dss.x509.tsp.MockTSP`

Comment: Seems `dss-demo-webapp` depends on `dss-mock-tsa`. Ensure your maven script resolves the dependency correctly.

Comment: @pedrofb : All the dependencies are resolved now, war file is created without any error messages, but it fails during catalina server startup, it doesn't start service.

Comment: To know what is happening, check the errors in the Tomcat log file or in the specific DSS log file that you have configured in the logback.xml file. You can update your question with the data of the problem, although I do not think it is related to your original question

Comment: You are right, it is a different topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p12 file is configurable in dss.properties file, base64 directly in request isn't supported:

```
Server signing token
dss.server.signing.keystore.type = PKCS12
dss.server.signing.keystore.filename = user_a_rsa.p12
dss.server.signing.keystore.password = password
```

In case of demo-webapp root of dss-demonstrations repository has to be rebuilt(`mvn clean install`) to put a new signing certificate to webapp.